# Can not get into the else part using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an issue while validating something using Angular.js. I have an array which contains some value i need to check those if that array value is not `null` then it should move into the else part but its not happening like that.I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.mulImage=[
    {
        image:'a.jpg',
        id:1
    },
    {
        image:'b.jpg',
        id:2
    }];
```

I am checking the above array using `if..else` condition like below.

```
if($scope.mulImage.length >0){
     for(var i=0;i<$scope.mulImage.length;i++){
        if($scope.mulImage[i]['image']==null){
            alert('Please select iamge'+(i+1));
            return;
        }
     }
}else{
    console.log('multiple image',$scope.mulImage);
}
```

In the above condition if array has some value at each iteration then the else part should execute but its not happening like that.I need if in each iteration of the loop `image` has some value then the else part should execute.Please help me.

Comment: what's the problem in appending `else{..}` statement with the `if` condition inside `for` loop?

Comment: i have to upload more data with this multiple image. I only gave the small part of code where i was getting problem.

Comment: Looking at this code your else will only execute when `$scope.mulImage.length == 0` ?

Comment: Yes,but here actually i need first it will check the array if `all image has some value` then it will get into the else part otherwise it will show the validation message.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"if that array value is not null then it should move into the else part "*. There is no `else` branch where you do the null check.

Comment: Do you mean null, like image:null, or not there in the object (undefined). Also it seems it would be easier to find or filter the null values and then test for length>0, and if you need it done so you can display something you could use an Angular filter

Answer (score 0):

Use should write your function like this.

```
var flag=true;
if($scope.mulImage.length >0){

 for(var i=0;i<$scope.mulImage.length;i++){
    if($scope.mulImage[i]['image']==null){
        alert('Please select iamge'+(i+1));
        flag=false;
        return;
         }
      }
 }
 if(flag==true){
  console.log('multiple image',$scope.mulImage);
 }
```

Comment: That looks uglier than OP's code. Please pay attention to formatting especially while answering. (Ideally always!)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `Array.prototype.any`, `Array.prototype.find` or `Array.prototype.findIndex` :

```
var nullImagesIndexes = $scope.mulImage.findIndex(item => item['image'] == null);

if (nullImagesIndexes) {
  alert("Please select image " + (nullImagesIndexes[0] + 1));
} else {
  console.log("multiple image", $scope.mulImage);
}
```